# HTML Background Fixed Position

Tags: html, css, scroll

I currently have a background fixed in my body tag

```
body
{
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/t3bikz8.jpg");
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

and i am also using "smoothscroll" feature, and i was hoping someone could help me out with 2 queries i have..

1) how do i make it that my background image only stays at the top of the page when you load, so it does not follow you down as you scroll.

2) secondly, i was hoping that the user would not be able to begin scrolling, unless they clicked one of my 4 available buttons on my main start up page. (i am bot sure is this command relevant to the background or not, sorry if its not)

thanks

hoping it will function like this background

http://www.andreagalanti.it/flatfy/

Comment: well for the background image you are using cover, which will cover the entire screen size. And you are using fixed attachment which will also make it appear on every scroll. Which is fine. I think what you want is a different background image per scroll? this may require some javascript to swop out the image.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't cancel or disable the scroll event, what I have seen people do is disable mouse scroll and arrow key scroll events. But a better approach is to not give the user anything to scroll to until one of the "buttons" has been clicked. You can do this by making your layout 100% height and display none of the extra stuff you want to hide and as the user progressing change each layout height and use display block or something. Just ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div and set its width/Height to 100% and set background image in div so when you scroll down you div will go up.

I don't know if it will work the way you want but you can try this
when you page loads the content that is visible without scrolling set it to fixed position and when user click buttons then change its position to relative/absolute with javascript.
Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` to the style could fix your issue.